# How do I stay on the page using HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

So I am trying to simulate a person being on my website, in this case it's my console application.

I can connect to it using a HttpWebRequest and create a WebRequest but it doesn't show as a person being on the website in my dashboard. However when I manually get on my website through my web browser it says that someone is online on the website in my dashboard system (WordPress),

So my question is, how do I accomplish the same thing, would I have to create a Socket connection? Or is this possible by using `KeepAlive` because I think the issue is that it's not on the page for long enough, it connect and gets the request but it doesnt actually establish a connection if that makes any sense. 
That's just my theory please correct me if I am wrong.

```
public static bool isServerOnline()
        {
            Boolean ret = false;

            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://arcticinnovative.com");
                req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer; // <= HERE
                req.Method = "HEAD";
                req.KeepAlive = false;
                HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    // HTTP = 200 - Internet connection available, server online
                    ret = true;
                }
                resp.Close();
                return ret;

            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                // Exception - connection not available
                Debug.Print("InternetUtils - isServerOnline - " + we.Status);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive?view=netframework-4.8), you can set KeepAlive to true in order to maintain a persistent connection.

Comment: That's what I thought but I don't think it's actually telling the server that it is connecting to tha "Hey, there is someone who established a connection and is still connected" and afaik, you can't set the time for it to "be alive". What if I want it to be alive to 10 seconds.

Comment: This depends on how a user is being detected. Is it from the Http Agent header, is it javascript execution that triggers on load? If so, you won't get javascript execution triggering from an HttpWebRequest. Evaluate your scenario when you can use something like Selenium, or PuppeteerSharp

Comment: Connecting using PuppeteerSharp worked just fine, I wonder what it is that makes it detect a connection.

Comment: My guess would be its allowing javascript execution on the page then performing the signaling. Watch the network panel in dev tools for XHR or WS. See anything you didnt specifically code up? I see off hand the page in your code is using google analytics. That would be one source.